# Storyboard designed for iOS7 not going fullscreen on iOS 6 on 4 inch device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uistoryboard

I am designing my iPhone app using `storyboard` and `auto-layout`. Everything works fine in **iOS 7** on both 4 inches and 3,5 inches device.

On **iOS 6.1** the app runs like is always on 3,5 inches device, even if is running on a 4 inches device, the black bars on top and bottom appears.

screenshot on the simulator:

[image]

Anyone with the same issue? how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you so much @NitinGohel that was exactly the problem!!! I forgot to add the splash for iOS 5,6!!! if you add the answer I will mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think are you Forget to adding splash screen **Default-568h@2x.png** in to you Project please check Property and set required splash-screen `Default-568h@2x.png (640 × 1136 pixels)`

Ones you add this image in to you working Project, Remove old Build from device or Simulatore, clear Project and re build and check Hope you issue will solve.

Comment: This also fixed my non-fullscreen problem when creating UITableViewController programmatically (no storyboards in entire project).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i'm agree with Nitin. In XCode 5 just create e new LaunchImage Set and add the standard, retina and R4 image in both iOS version (5,6 and 7).

Remember to set this set as default in your project info.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to replace Launch Images with your Storyboard.
In Xcode, go to Target > General, and then:

[image]