# Autolayout not working on iOS7 and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

I've started using Xcode auto layout for my projects.
Auto-layout works perfectly when I'm testing on ios8 devices, it the view scales as needed.
However, things get a little crazy with ios7.

When I test my app on an ios7 iPhone 5 simulator, the app **doesn't scale-up to the larger screen**,
but only shows the 3.5 inch view, leaving **black bars on the top and bottom of the screen**.

I am using a tableView controller.

How do I scale the tableViewController up so that it fits on a larger screen in ios7?

(Like I've said, my app fits perfectly in ios8, on all screen sizes, but not in ios7.
Also, it scales fine on an ios7 ipad.)

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storyboard designed for iOS7 not going fullscreen on iOS 6 on 4 inch device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399624/storyboard-designed-for-ios7-not-going-fullscreen-on-ios-6-on-4-inch-device)

Comment: Ios7 doesn't have size classes. Usually, you get a compiler warning about this, but...? If your storyboard has them enabled, it probably breaks things on iOS 7.

Comment: I had similar issue. The solution for me to delete LaunchScreen.xib and revert back to it 'Use asset catalog option'

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode (6) IDE should give a warning about this, that may not be so clear:

"**Applications using Launch Screen Files and targetting iOS 7.1 and earlier

need to also include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog.**"

This means you need to have the proper Launch-Images for the "**Retina 4**" screen,
which is **640 × 1136 pixels**, and it should be configured in the assets-catalog,
just like your Application-Icons ("AppIcon"), but under "**LaunchImage**" there.

Once you add this 4-inch-compatible Launch-Image to your application,
iOS-7 will assume you are properly supporting the "**Retina 4**" screen,
and will launch the application in 4-inch mode.